# overcome overflow:hidden property of parent element

Tags: javascript, css

By clicking on a button I'm adding new elements to the list. Each element has its own message that is absolutely positioned against this element. This works fine until I add 'overflow:hidden' property to the parent list element. Obviously, the message is hidded. If the overflow:hiddne property must be in place, how can I show message for each new element?
Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdDd4/) and the code:

HTML:

```
<span id='click-me'>Click me</span>
<ul id='list'></ul>
```

CSS:

```
#list {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.option {
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    position:relative;
}
.message {
    width: 79px;
    height: 20px;
    background: gray;
    position: absolute;
    right: -90px;
    top: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#click-me').click(function() {
    $('#list').append("<li class='option'><div class='message'>I'm message</div></li>");
});
```

EDIT:
I tried playing with overflow-x and overflow-y properties. But somehow it's not doing what I expect it to do. Adding these properties to the #list element:

```
#list {
    ...
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:visible;
}
```

creates bottom scrollbar. Is it expected behavior?

Comment: I don't know that this question makes much sense.  If your parent element is hidden then it is not rendered, thus all of its children should not be rendered either...

Comment: @Subterfuge, parent element is not hidden. It has overflow:hidden property set

Comment: My bad... My eyes seem to be betraying me :).

Answer (score 1):

Change `height` of `#list` to `min-height`.

Check the [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/AdDd4/1/).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how that solves the problem. The message is still not displayed.

Comment: It makes `#list` expanding when adding more than 5 items. `.message` isn't displayed because you use `right: -90px` and list being 100px.

Comment: Why do you put a div inside a li, if I may ask? What's the thought on that?

Comment: I guess I didn't make myself clear. Try removing overflow:hidden property from the #list element, and you will see the behavior I want to get

Comment: >>Why do you put a div inside a li, if I may ask? What's the thought on that? ---- This is simplified example so don't pay attention to it :)

Comment: Ok, I understand now, why must overflow: hidden stay?

Comment: Because the #list element is custom scrollbar control, which is implemented with overflow:hidden property - you can examine this scrollbar [here](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/). Check out <div class="viewport"> element on the scrollbar

Comment: Late to the party, but please remember that min-height is not supported in older versions of IE.